# problem by using display math mode

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to write an equation using display math mode but I'm facing some problems :

1. the equations aren't centered
2. the equations coming in one line even when I separate them using (double)`\\`

```
    \begin{equation}
    G_t = R_{t+1} + \gamma R_{t+2} +\gamma^2 R_{t+3} + \gamma^3 R_{t+4}+\dots \\

    G_t = R{t+1} + \gamma( R_{t+2} +\gamma R_{t+3} + \gamma^2 R_{t+4}+\dots) \\
 
    G_t = R_{t+1} + \gamma G_{t+1}\\

    \end{equation}
```

Comment: The equation environment is for single equations. `\\ ` doesn't generate a line break within the equation environment. Perhaps you need something like the `align` environment.

Comment: thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @IanThompson said in the comments, the `equation` environment is made for equations spanning a single line. There are other environments, such as `align`, `alignat` and `gather`, which should be used when multiple lines of equations are to be displayed. If you want the equations to be centered, you can use `gather` like in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
G_t = R_{t+1} + \gamma R_{t+2} +\gamma^2 R_{t+3} + \gamma^3 R_{t+4}+\dots \\
G_t = R{t+1} + \gamma( R_{t+2} +\gamma R_{t+3} + \gamma^2 R_{t+4}+\dots) \\
G_t = R_{t+1} + \gamma G_{t+1}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, here it might be more appropriate not to center every equation, but rather to center the block as a whole, and to align the equal signs. For this the `align` environment can be used as in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
G_t & = R_{t+1} + \gamma R_{t+2} +\gamma^2 R_{t+3} + \gamma^3 R_{t+4}+\dots \\
    & = R{t+1} + \gamma( R_{t+2} +\gamma R_{t+3} + \gamma^2 R_{t+4}+\dots) \\
    & = R_{t+1} + \gamma G_{t+1}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also that display math environments do not accept blank lines, which is why I removed them from your example.

Comment: This looks like simplification on successive lines. I would use `align` with `G_t` on the first line only.

Comment: @IanThompson I would do the same, but I used `gather` since the OP specified that one of the problems was that the equations were not centered. But this is indeed ambiguous; I will add another solution with `align`.